# How to add tooltip to table headers in element-ui (vue.js)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I thought this would work but it did not:

```
<template lang="pug">
  el-table(:data="myDataSet")
    el-table-column
      template(slot="label")
        el-tooltip(content="Verification of Reference")
          | VOR Status
      template(slot-scope="props")
        | {{ props.row.myData }}
</template>
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<el-table-column prop="value"
                 label="Value"
                 :render-header="renderPhaseHeader">
</el-table-column>

methods: {
  renderPhaseHeader(h, { column }) {
    return h('span', {
      class: 'class-name-if-you-want'
    }, [
      column.label + " ",
      h('el-tooltip', {
        class: 'class-name-if-you-want',
        attrs: {
          'content': 'message',
          'effect': 'light',
          'placement': 'top-start'
        }
      }, [
        h('i', {
          class: 'far fa-question-circle'
        })
      ])
    ])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use slot="header"

```
      <el-table-column>
        <template
          slot="header">
          <el-popover
            ref="fromPopOver"
            placement="top-start"
            width="250"
            trigger="hover">
            <span>
             Tooltip info here
            </span>
          </el-popover>
          <span>Destination <i
            v-popover:fromPopOver
            class="el-icon-info
            text-blue" />
          </span>
        </template>
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <span>{{ scope.row.SomeData }}</span>
        </template>
```